# Join results from two different data sources in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I have two databases hosted on two different servers. We'll call the two tables `tblABC` and `tblDEF`. They each have a dataset associated with them, `dsABC` and `dsDEF`:

**dsABC**

| PersonID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jane |
| 3 | Jake |

**tblDEF**

| PaymentID | PersonID | AccountID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | XXXXX-XXXX |
| 101 | 2 | XXXXX-XXXX |
| 102 | 5 | XXXXX-XXXX |

In my current situation, `dsABC` is run automatically as soon as the report is loaded. I then want to use the results in the `dsABC.PersonID` column as a parameter to the SQL query for `dsDEF`. So, for example, `dsDEF` would only have payments `100` and `101`.

When I try to use a `LookupSet` as the parameter for `dsDEF`, I get an error. So, as a workaround, I created an "Internal Parameter" where the default values were the `PersonID` results from `dsABC`. That Internal Parameter was then used as a parameter for `dsDEF` so that I can filter the results accordingly.

Of course, the examples above are simplistic, and in PROD `tblABC` and `tblDEF` both have  100k+ rows. I'm wondering if there is some sort of limitation I'm about to hit when I attempt to apply this same logic when dealing with much larger datasets.

**My question:** Is this the only way to do this? Or, is there another way to chain datasets where the results of one dataset is used as a parameter for another dataset? I am trying to rule out Linked Servers and JOINs using four-part names.

Comment: A few things. `1.` What the error you got using LOOKUPSET? `2.` I suspect you will hit a limit if you are trying to pass several thousand ID's as part of a WHERE clause. `3.` Is there a reason you are avoiding using linked servers?

Comment: `1.` I get the following error: "The expression used for the parameter '@pPersonIDList' in the dataset 'dsDEF' refers to a field. Fields cannot be used in query parameter expressions". I am using the following expression `LookupSet(1,1,Fields!PersonID.Value, "dsABC")`

Comment: `2.` Does not appear to require a response from me other than what I mentioned in my question above, which is that I suspect I will eventually run into a limitation so looking for alternative methods.

Comment: `3.` Linked servers expect that there are firewall policies allowing cross-SQL traffic between the two SQL servers, which I suspect people want to get rid of eventually. Also, these two SQL servers are in the same data center at the moment. I can, however, see a future where they will be in different data centres (e.g. one in AWS and the other on-premise). In that situation, Linked Servers would not work thus why I am posting this question here.

Comment: Linked servers can still work, in my environment we have on-premise servers with linked servers pointing to servers hosted on AWS. I'm not sure you have many other options. Can you schedule a job to take a copy of the remote data onto your local server each night? Just a thought, I don't know enough about your exact setup to offer any more.

Comment: Are there no further answers/ideas for this? I would think there must be lots of situations where people need to use results from one dataset to filter another. e.g. Using results from an Oracle DB as a filter within a 'WHERE' clause in a SQL query. Is that really not the case?